# "heap corruption" in OpenCV using findContours()

Tags: c++, opencv

I am going to find text region of an image using OpenCV(C++ in VS 2015). But when running my debugger throws "Access violation reading location". I located where occurs error:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(sobeled, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

`cv::Mat sobeled` is a processed grayscale image, which displays well in imshow() function.

Also I checked call stack, it was "ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12()" on the top.

So I wonder how to deal with this problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: is sobeled a 8 bit single channel image? If it is really a sobel output, then probably it is floating point or 16 bit signed matrix.

Comment: You're probably using debug libs in release, or viceversa. Or libs built with another compiler. Have you rebuilt opencv with vc14?

Comment: I checked and found I did use release libs in debug.Thanks a lot!